# scss + zurb foundation error in compiling

Tags: 7

I inherited a job done by a third party and I need to do some modification  including making of CSS operations.

The site uses a child theme of Zurb Foundation (I always used Bootstrap ). Now if I compile the .scss files (for example custom.scss), I get:

> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation / components / global.

The directory with the "original" version of ZURB foundation theme (the parent) exists.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Koala to create the final CSS, but I think this is not important.

Comment: What version is the installed foundation theme? Have you got Foundation 1.0.3 gem or higher installed?

Comment: Does it have it's own grunt/gulpfile to compile the CSS?